# How can create the chart with multiple background colors on React Native

Tags: react-native, d3.js, charts

How can I create a background for a chart that looks like this using D3 chart, or any chart support React Native

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vage but I'll try to help you. If u want to create a chart on D3 you'll use a `SVG` element, in that case I think the solution is to use their color Scheme to define the color of the `SVG` element. 
This [link](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic) will redirect you to the d3-scale-chromatic where you can find different types of color schemes to you. 
You can also see this [link](https://observablehq.com/@d3/color-schemes) for different approach.

If you want a solid color for your SVG you just need to write the following code on the SVG attributes:

```
.style("fill", "red")
```

If you want a color Scheme you should do something like this:

```
//Create before appending SVG element
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeSet3); //Choose the scheme you want

    .style("fill", function(){
        return color
    }
```

I hope it helps